# prettyphoto iframe

Tags: prettyphoto

I am using prettyphoto to display web pages in an iframe. Does any one know the element id which contain the unique value of the web page http:// reference? Since they don't have an id I thought I could use that.

thank you.

I am getting somewhere.

alert( $("#pp_full_res").html());

gives me

> iframe src="http://xxxx.com/zzz/html" iframeborder="no" height="640"
>   etc etc

how can I grab just the src?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Building on your example above in order to get to the actual iframe src you can use the attr() method of JQuery.

var sSrc = $("#pp_full_res").attr('src');

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own iframe reference when iniatializating prettyPhoto:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
  iframe_markup: '<iframe id="name-here" name="name-here" src ="{path}" width="{width}" height="{height}" frameborder="no"></iframe>',
});
```